# Insert data from multiple text boxes into sql via ajax

Tags: javascript, php

Not sure of the best way do this.

On my page I have the following (which pulls a list of custom questions from my database set by a user)

**PHP PAGE THAT SHOWS THE QUESTIONS / COVER LETTER TEXT AREA**

```
    $questions = $this->db->get_where("applicationquestions", 
    ["opportunity_id" => $contact->id]);
        $questionsfound = $questions->num_rows();
        $questions = $questions->result();


<? foreach ($question as $q):?>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="<?echo $q->id;?>" class="control-label"><? echo $q->label;? 
>:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="<?echo $q->id;?>" name="<?echo $q->id;?>">
</div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

and using ajax / javascript i am passing information via POST

** THE JS ** 
    $("#apply").click(function(e) {
                        e.preventDefault();

```
  var oppid = "<?echo $opportunity->id;?>";


                    $.ajax({
                            url: 
  "https://MYSITEHERE/submitapplication",
                            method: "POST",
                            data: {oppid:oppid}}); });
```

What i am wondering is the best way to get then insert the questions id and the users answer into my database through this method.

** Submit Application File / Function **

```
public function submitapplication() {

$insert['opportunity_id']= $this->input->post('oppid');
$insert['user_id']= is_user_logged_in();
$insert['time']= time();
$insert['coverletter']= $this->input->post('coverletter');
$this->db->insert("applications", $insert);
```

// here i would need it to submit the answers from the question textboxes into the table applicationanswers along with the question id

```
        }
```

**HTML THAT IS DISPLAYED AFTER PHP HAS LISTED QUESTION FIELDS**

```
<form id="applyform" class="">
 <div class="row">
 <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
  <label>Cover Letter</label>
 <textarea class="form-control" id="coverletter" name="coverletter" rows="7" placeholder="Start typing a cover letter"></textarea>
```

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label for="1" class="control-label">Have you sold web design before?: 
 </label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="1">
                                                    </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label for="2" class="control-label">Do you like monkeys?:</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="2">
                                                    </div>




                                                     </div>      </div>    
                                                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using more than one item in your form, I would suggest using

```
var data = $('form').serialize();
```

This will pass all of the form values to your php script and then you can use php to insert them.

```
$("#apply").click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
var oppid = "<?echo $opportunity->id;?>";

var data = $('form').serialize();
                $.ajax({
                        url: 
 "https://MYSITEHERE/submitapplication",
                        method: "POST",
                        data: {formdata:data}}); });
```

You would then just parse the data in your php

Comment: I tried that, the issue is i have it already inserting stuff into a seperate table, such as the oppid and users id (into applications table) and then want to pass the answers to the table opportunityanswers.

I tried the above code you sent and it seems to be posting the following : coverletter=fdsfsdf&question=%20

Even though i put answers in both questions

Comment: Can you show me what html is parsed when you run the page which generates the list of functions?

Comment: Hi mate, i have updated the question with everything, let me know if you need anything else?

Comment: The html that is rendered. I see the ID has a value, but the textbox do no have the name attribute, that's why the data is not being passed back with the serialize function.

Comment: After putting the name tag in, it's posting the info like this now thedata:coverletter=hahahha&1=yeah&2=no (including thedata:) is this right?

Comment: Yes thats right. Now you just need to parse that data in your php script on the server.